# how to set criteria in cgal 3d mesh?

Tags: cgal

I am using C-Gal for 3d mesh generation from segmented images. However I don't understand exactly how the mesh criteria work and I setting them through trials. How I can optimize my choice?

Thanks,
Konstantinos.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're using the default classes.
Criteria are details on their respective documentation pages:

- [Mesh_criteria_3](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/classCGAL_1_1Mesh__criteria__3.html)
- [Mesh_cell_criteria_3](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/classCGAL_1_1Mesh__cell__criteria__3.html)
- [Mesh_facet_criteria_3](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/classCGAL_1_1Mesh__facet__criteria__3.html)
- [Mesh_edge_criteria_3](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/classCGAL_1_1Mesh__edge__criteria__3.html)